# Input Text Box Returns Undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, text, box

Here is my HTML:

```
<form name='cred' class="panel-body2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for='addjidlbl'> Username (JID):</label>
    <input type='text' id='addjid' />
  </div>
  <input type='button' id='add' value='add' />
</form>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
$('#add').bind('click', function() {
  var jid = $('#addjid').value; 
  alert(jid);
  //var jid=document.getElementById('addjid').value;    
  var jid2 =$('#addjid').get(0).value; 
  alert(jid2);
  //  //$('#addjid').get(0).value; 
  log('jid=>'+jid);
  var data = document.getElementById("addjid").value; //$(".panel.panel-default2#addjid").value;
  alert(data);

  alert("type=>"+ typeof(jid));
  addRoster(jid);
});

function addRoster(jid) {
  log('addRoster=>' + jid);
}
```

What I get are two message boxes with "undefined" and third with "type=>undefined".  Why can't I get the input text of the `addjid` text box?

If I change `var jid = $('#addjid').get(0).value;`, `jid` is just blank even when the textbox has value. Why?

Comment: use the jquery way to get the value `.val()`... `$('#addjid').val()`

Comment: @PedroEstrada it returns blank.

Comment: please see the code snippet in my answer.

Comment: @PedroEstrada thank you for the explanation.  Problem was I a <div tag before this tag with  id='addjid' that the script was return that value.  When I change the id to be unique, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have it working using `.val()`

add some text to the text box and
click on the add button and the alert will popup

```js
$('#add').on('click', function() {
  alert($('#addjid').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name='cred' class="panel-body2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for='addjidlbl'> Username (JID):</label>
      <input type='text' id='addjid' />
    </div>
  <input type='button' id='add' value='add' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Change .value to .val() like

> $('#addjid').value

should be

> $('#addjid').val()

Comment: var jid=$('#addjid').val(); alert(jid); message box is blank.

Comment: You tried that after entering some value in the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
$('#addjid').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using id's to get the value you will only have one element with the given id. When you do .get(0) or any index you are typically trying to get the value out of a given array of values. For Ex

```
<li>first</li> //0
<li>second</li> //1
```

Here in a structure like this you will do something like 
    $("li").get(0)

It will give you the first item with in li.

and to get the value you will need to use **.val()**

So you can use

```
 $('#addjid').val()
```

Hope this helps you.

Happy Learning :)

Comment: Glad it helped :) Please consider accepting the question